# Left my car key on/in the door?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to make a sentence describing this image.

[image: http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/643621/180228929/stock-photo-left-key-on-the-car-door-at-parking-lot-180228929.jpg]

So, I left my car key on the car door. OR I left my car key in the car door. OR I left my car key put in the car door.

Which one is correct? Or is there a better way to say it?

Comment: On the car door. http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/left-key-on-the-car-door-photo-p220931

Comment: I left my key _in the keyhole_. :^) @Laure - your picture shows there's no single answer to this question. My instincts tell me to use _in_ rather than _on_, but those pesky prepositions can be hard to nail down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Key in the car door` is the right use of it.

For reference check [this result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22key%20in%20the%20car%20door%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) from google books.

There is absolutely no reference for the other use in any book there.

Answer (score 2):

ON the door would mean that the key is sitting on top of the door. That's clearly not what is meant here.

IN the door is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> I left my car key **in** the car door (lock).

*lock* is implied since you can't put a key inside the door anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

HAHA I love that link to the stock photo titled_Left Key ON the car door - now I understand why you asked.  But that is incorrect.  They are not 'on' the door, they're IN the door.  As user 3169 stated, people understand they are in the lock as a given.

So, definitely - IN the door.  I've actually never heard anyone say 'on' the door.  If you left it 'on' your door, I guess it would be laying on the window ledge or something. HAHA

Saying 'I left my car key put in the car door' is incorrect.  I thought about it and on a SEARCH for stock images I'm more specific. I would start with: 'keys left in car door', then search: 'car keys left in door' - You can cover 3 car key in door searches by using these search parameters:  'car-keys-left-in-car-door-lock-in-parking-lot-garage'

:D   [image: where are my car keys?]